# Django model : save object with custom field

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to know how I can do that : save an object in my database through Django model with custom field.

This is my modelclass :

```
class Document(EdqmTable):

    language = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name=_('language'), choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, null=False)
    format = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=_('format'), choices=FORMAT_CHOICES, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('document title'), null=False)
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, verbose_name=_('publication title'), null=False,
                                    related_name='documents')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('document')
        verbose_name_plural = _('documents')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = f"{self.publication.pub_id}-{self.format.upper()}"
        super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have a `save` method, which let to define my field `title` with combination between two fields.
`title` field is hidden in my django form and is set automatically by Django.

But, up to now, it doesn't work because my object is not saved into my database. Something is wrong in my `save` function ?

**EDIT :**

I edited my post with forms.py file and my view :

The field `document.title` is used in my django forms with formset like this :

```
class PublicationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].empty_label = _('Select a category')  # Modify initial empty_label

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ['title', 'pub_id', 'category']


class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['publication', 'language', 'format', 'title', 'upload']


DocumentFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Publication, Document, form=DocumentForm, extra=1)
```

And my view according to this part :

```
class PublicationCreateView(EdqmCreateView):
    """ Create publication with document form through formset """
    model = Publication
    template_name = 'freepub/publication_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PublicationCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['document_form'] = DocumentFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None)

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        document = context['document_form']
        if document.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            document.instance = self.object
            document.save()
        return super(PublicationCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('publication-list-crud')
```

Comment: What is an `EdqmTable`?

Comment: Just a specific class which add automatically `creation_date` and `modification_date` fields. I apologize if I miss to explain this class :/

Comment: but it inherits from `Model`? Can you make a MWE how you construct such `Document` record in the database?

Comment: Yes it inherits from `Model` ;) Hum what do you mean with `MWE` ?

Comment: Please show where you are calling this, including the code of the view and the form.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this class. You should provide code that makes it possible for us to reproduce your issue. [mcve]. The problem could be with the parent class or somewhere else in your code. Does your code raise any exceptions?

Comment: Thank you, I will show you my entire code with my view and my form file